# Change height of Navigation bar in Twenty Eleven theme

Tags: wordpress

I need to change menu height to 41px; in Twenty Eleven theme.

I follow [this steps](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/edit-navigation-bar-in-twenty-eleven-theme).

[image]

And get this. I need to increase height of menu "about" box but also need the menu be responsive.

Comment: Use `twentyTwelve` theme, it's responsive.

Comment: Twenty Eleven is responsive too. My question is to fix the bug in image.